# ssh'ing for remote access fails with operation timed out

Tags: terminal, network, ssh, remote-desktop

I have a mac that has remote control set up. I'm trying to ssh (from my own mac) using

```
ssh username@IP_address
```

It hangs for a few seconds and then it says operation timed out. Interestingly, I can ping the same IP address successfully. I can also run the `traceroute` command and see it start from my mac's IP and end up at the target IP in 3 steps.

What is the next thing I can check to figure out why we can't `ssh` into this machine?

**Edit:** the output of the ssh command with the verbose mode:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxxxx port 22.
ssh: connect to host xxxxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Try verbose mode and see if that gives any hints:  ssh -v username@IP_address

Comment: @Buadhai I tried it and added the output to the post.

Comment: You get get even more debug output with `-vvv`, but currently it looks as if `sshd` isn't running on the remote machine, or at least not accepting connections. Do you have physical access to it so you can verify some things there?

Comment: @nohillside I have verified that the remote machine has `ssh` working fine, as I can ssh into my own laptop from the remote machine. I tried the `-vvv` flag but the output is the same as the one with the `-v` flag.

Comment: Are you sure that the remote machine is running ssh on port 22? Is that port open on the remote router and is it forwarded to that machine. Is there a firewall issue?

Comment: Login in from the remote machine doesn‘t require sshd to run there, sshd is only required on the machine you log into.

Comment: What happens if you run `ssh localhost` on your remote machine?

Comment: @Buadhai when I check in system preferences, the firewall is turned off. When I check `/etc/services` it shows that ssh uses port 22. I don't know what else to check?

Comment: @unbeatable101 it prompted password. I couldn't log in because I don't know what password to enter, but it did "connect".

Comment: @nohillside how do I check if sshd is running or not?

Comment: you already did, by running `ssh localhost` on the remote machine.

Comment: I think you should try unloading and reloading the sshd service on the host Mac: sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist followed by sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist. This morning I tried to ssh into my iMac from a Raspberry Pi: ssh: connect to host mrmuscle port 22: Connection timed out. I unloaded and reloaded the service on the iMac and then it worked: Last login: Fri Nov 12 05:42:04 2021 from 192.168.0.65.